# How to load ".npy" file into Blender?

Tags: python, scripting, file-format, point-clouds

I have a 3-dimensional volume array of size (64, 64, 64) which has an extension of ".npy". I wanted to visualize in Blender so that I can do post-processing work from the software.

1. I tried loading through script as np.load('data.npy') after importing numpy library. It did not show me any error, but I am unable to visualize it.
2. Is there a way I could load ".npy" file extension in Blender and visualize it. Or, is there a way I can convert the possible format for blender.

Answer (score 2):

**Numpy point cloud**

Test script.

- Get the verts of context object
- Save as `test.npy`
- Load saved file
- Create mesh with saved verts
- Add mesh to new object and link to scene

Test script

```
import bpy
import numpy as np

context = bpy.context
ob = context.object
me = ob.data
# get the coords of context object
coords = np.empty(len(me.vertices) * 3)
me.vertices.foreach_get("co", coords)
print(coords.reshape(-1, 3))
# save to .npy file
np.save('test.npy', coords.reshape(-1, 3))
#load it into another array
verts = np.load('test.npy')
print(verts)
# new mesh
me = bpy.data.meshes.new("Verts")
# load in verts
me.from_pydata(verts, [], [])
# create object and link to scene
vob = bpy.data.objects.new("Verts", me)
context.collection.objects.link(vob)
# give same global transform
#vob.matrix_world = ob.matrix_world
```